# MySQL - Select defined values even if the result is zero

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I have the following query result:

[image]

and would like to have a value for B, C, and D for each 'einfacheWanddicke'. Even if the value is zero.
The result should look like this:

[image]

So far the query looks like this:

```
Select
  tbl_rts_proben.einfacheWanddicke,
  lims.tbl_rts_aufnahmen.bewertungsGruppe As Bewertung,
  Count(tbl_rts_aufnahmen.bewertungsGruppe) As Anzahl
From
  tbl_rts_proben Left Join
  v_auftragsuebersicht_zfp_php_ag_oe On
    v_auftragsuebersicht_zfp_php_ag_oe.`LIMS Nummer` = tbl_rts_proben.limsNummer
  Inner Join
  tbl_rts_aufnahmen On tbl_rts_proben.id = tbl_rts_aufnahmen.probenID Inner Join
  tbl_rts_auswertung On tbl_rts_aufnahmen.id = tbl_rts_auswertung.aufnahmenID
  Inner Join
  tbl_rts_fehler On tbl_rts_fehler.fehlerID = tbl_rts_auswertung.fehlerID
Where
  v_auftragsuebersicht_zfp_php_ag_oe.StatusID = 3 And
  Year(v_auftragsuebersicht_zfp_php_ag_oe.erstellungsdatum) = '2020' And
  tbl_rts_proben.probenArtID = 2
Group By
  tbl_rts_proben.einfacheWanddicke, lims.tbl_rts_aufnahmen.bewertungsGruppe,
  tbl_rts_aufnahmen.bewertungsGruppe
Order By
  Bewertung
```

Is there a way to specify a kind of array (B, C, D)?

The reason for the question is my problem that I cannot create a stacked column chart in C # with the missing data.

Comment: Looks like you should replace all `Inner Join` to `Left Join`.

Comment: unfortunately no success.
The values B, C and D come from cell values and are not a table reference

Comment: Are all the expected combinations of _einfacheWanddicke_ and _B,C,D_ values available at database level? EDIT: or at least separately all the available _einfacheWanddicke_ and _bewertung_ values e.g. in two tables?

Comment: not really. einfacheWanddicke is a free text entry, just like the bewertung B, C or D. I would need a function that looks for each occurring value under einfacheWanddicke which number for B, which number for C and which number for D :/ and if there is no number, insert a 0

Comment: It looks that any possible runtime values of _B,C,somebodyEnteredEInsteadOfD_ are available in `tbl_rts_aufnahmen.bewertungsGruppe` and the count depends on records in `tbl_rts_auswertung`  and `tbl_rts_fehler` right? _Did you tried replacing all 3 inner joins to left joins and checked the query result?_ Not in your UI but in mysql console.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a kind of 'aray' in MySQL using this query:

```
select substr('BCD', @i:=@i+1, 1) as AAA from tbl_rts_proben join (select @i := 0) as T where @i < 3;
```

(tbl_rts_proben must have at least 3 rows to get 3 resulting rows). You can use this query for JOINs in a way like:

```
select N.*, T.AAA from tbl_rts_proben as N
    join (select substr('BCD', @i:=@i+1, 1) as AAA from new_table1 join (select @i := 0) as T where @i < 3) as T;
```

But I can't yet imagine a request that gives your result above. But maybe it is a question of some more efforts...